# Per-app connection blocking tool

Tags: linux, open-source, firewall

1. Is there a free software tool for GNU/Linux based OS similar to NetGuard for android?

or

2. Is there a free software firewall tool that allows black/whitelisting IP on a per-app/process basis?

Note: A tool called PortMaster nearly meets my requirement but it is in alpha dev phase.